# template function pointers and lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, variadic

Hi I'm trying to sort out an issue with the following code:

```
template<typename... Args>
using Func = void (*)(Args... args);

template<typename... Args>
void do_test(Func<Args&...> f, Args&... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; i++)
      f(args...);
}

int main(){
    int x = 0;
    do_test(Func<int&>([](int &y) { y++; }), x);  // OK

    // Error - mismatched types 'void (*)(Args& ...)' and 'main()::<lambda(int&)>'
    do_test([](int &y) { y++; }, x);

    return x;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/UaXxFJ

Can anyone explain why it is necessary to wrap the lambda in `Func<int&>( )`? Is there a way to avoid it? - because if the argument list is non-trivial it becomes quite tedious having to list out the argument types twice.

The goal here is to make a visitor pattern that the compiler can optimize away. I'm using it for an image processing algorithm where I want to reuse the code of the outer loops, with various bits of inner code. The `Args` are being used as something similar to a lambda capture, except using traditional function pointers so that the compiler can optimize them away - which it seems not to be able to do with `std::function<>`

Comment: Black magic spell : add `+`. Example : `do_test(+[](int &y) { y++; }, x);`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - what? that's crazy. so doing some integer/pointer math on the function pointer, strips it of the lamda-ness in the compiler's eyes?

Comment: Captureless lambdas are convertible to function pointers. Using `+` forces that conversion. What I'm not sure about is why that conversion isn't automatically used by `do_test`. Usually, that indicates that two implicit conversions are involved which is too many, but I don't see exactly what it is here. So I'm not sure why *not* using `+` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just allow the function to take any type, whether function pointer or lambda:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void do_test(F f, Args&... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; i++)
      f(args...);
}
```

Depending on your use case, consider taking `f` by-`const`-reference or *forwarding reference* (i.e. `F&&`), as well.

You should also consider changing the way you take the `args` function parameters. Usually in such a situation you would take them by *forwarding reference*, meaning `Args&&... args` instead of `Args&... args`. Otherwise you won't be able to call the function with rvalues arguments.

---

Or if you have some specific reason to accept only this one specific function pointer type, you can make the first function parameter a non-deduced context, given that the template arguments can already be deduced from the other function parameters:

```
template<typename... Args>
void do_test(std::type_identity_t<Func<Args&...>> f, Args&... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 100; i++)
      f(args...);
}
```

`std::type_identity_t` is a C++20 feature, but can be easily implemented:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;
```

Everything left to the scope resolution operator `::` in `type_identity<T>::type` is a non-deduced context and so the first function parameter will not be used to deduce the `Args`, which in turn means that implicit conversions will be considered (e.g. the lambda to function pointer conversion).

Alternatively, as mentioned by @FrançoisAndrieux in the question comments, you can use the lambda `+` trick to convert the lambda to a function pointer at the call site:

```
do_test(+[](int &y) { y++; }, x);
```

Also note that taking a function pointer of this specific type means that the function can only be called with functions that have *exactly* this type. For example `args` is always deduced to a reference type, so any possible function than may be used with this one must take only reference parameters. This is usually not what you want. Usually you want the loose behavior of `std::function<R(Args...)>`, which can be constructed from any function object that is *callable* with the specified `Args` and returns something that can be implicitly converted to `R`.

Comment: Do you happen to have any idea why the original code doesn't work?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It tries to deduce the `Args...` template arguments in `void (*)(Args... args)`, but fails because the lambda is not a function pointer.

Comment: I also thought it was a deduction problem. But I've tried providing `Args` explicitly with `do_test<int>` and it still won't take the lambda.

Comment: @walnut Good point - and this allows me to use lambda captures which are much better than my reference-args passing construct

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Even if you provide some of the template arguments, because it is a parameter pack, there could still be more not explicitly specified, so the first function parameter still needs to be deduced from.

Comment: @walnut That's interesting. I hadn't thought about that. It's not because you provide parts of a parameter pack that it can't continue to deduce more parameters.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't intend OP to `std::move`/`std::forward` from the arguments in each call. But the `&&` is necessary to be able to pass rvalues at all. The only alternative would be `const Args&`, but then it won't work with non-`const` arguments.

Comment: @walnut I see, you're thinking of for example `do_test([](int &y) { y++; }, 10);`. My concern was if the given function had an rvalue reference parameter. Edit : I guess it's a bad example, because `y` is a lvalue reference. Maybe `do_test([](int y) { std::cout << y << '\n'; }, 10);` is a better example

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Right that was the example I meant. (Didn't see your edited comment until now).